# Windows FTP client with cloud site manager?

Tags: windows, ftp, cloud-service, sftp

Long time user of [CuteFTP](http://www.cuteftp.com/), and now looking for something better. Can anyone recommend software that does the following?

- Cloud storage of all my site logins (not file storage, just "Site Manager" stuff)
- Quick access between different folders (e.g., root to root, wp-content/themes to wp-content/themes etc. I spend forever traversing directories)

I'm a web designer by trade with 100's of different FTP sites configured currently, so any recommendations that would speed up the constant up/down of files, directory switching etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> Quick access between different folders (eg root to root, wp-content/themes to wp-content/themes etc. I spend forver traversing directories)

[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) has [synchronized browsing](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_navigate#synchronize_browsing) and [bookmarks](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_navigate#bookmarks).

> Cloud storage of all my site logins (not file storage, just "Site Manager" stuff)

I think you mean sharing FTP client config/credentials across machines? You can set WinSCP to [store the config in an ini file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/config) and sync this file across machines using a self-hosted cloud storage solution something like [Owncloud](http://alternativeto.net/software/owncloud/), [Seafile](http://alternativeto.net/software/seafile/), or plain Dropbox (remember to encrypt your config/credentials before uploading)...

There's even a guide to [Sharing WinSCP configuration between machines using cloud storage](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_config_cloud).

Comment: Yes that's right, sharing configuration across different machines. I was looking at a login solution such as the way Chrome & Firefox sync bookmarks, but your suggestion is something to consider too.

Comment: You can also do the config file synchronization from an USB stick or do it from WinSCP itself

Answer (score 2):

[Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.io/) should fit your needs just fine, supports a lot of protocols/services such as FTP, SFTP, WebDAV, Amazon S3 and OpenStack Swift, is free and released under a GPL license.

Bookmark section which stores your servers, paths and credentials :
[image: Bookmarks screenshot]

Folder screenshot on a Windows system connecting to a Linux SSH server :
[image: Folder screenshot]

And most importantly, its interface isn't ugly and bloated, unlike most of the [other FTP](http://a.fsdn.com/con/app/proj/filezilla/screenshots/fz3_win_main.png) [clients](http://winscp.net/pad/screenshot.png).

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [WebDrive](http://www.webdrive.com/products/webdrive/)

WebDrive has an extremely user-friendly interface and is available for Windows, Mac, Android, and iOS.

You can use it to access and edit files in place on many server types and protocols including SFTP, FTP over SSL, Amazon S3, WebDAV, Google Drive, and DropBox. This is a huge time saver for someone with multiple sites to manage, because you can access these servers just like a drive letter on your computer. WebDrive allows custom UNC naming as well, so you have access to unlimited servers/sites.

Comment: Is onedrive support planned?  If so when will that be available for webdrive?

Comment: Ryan, OneDrive support for WebDrive for Windows became available in March. And our newest release of the Mac version supports OneDrive as well.